# Constantly add multiple mysql database rows into a html table using a dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, dropdown

I have a small project that I need some help with!

I have a MYSQL database containing: 'ID' 'FoodTitle' 'Serving' 'Carbs' 'Protein' 'Fat'

Now, I have the 'FoodTitle' column in a dropdown menu. So whenever a user selects what food they want the 'Serving' 'Carbs' 'Protein' 'Fat' column in that praticular row displays in its appropriate text input inside a html table.

I would like the user to be able to keep selecting 'FoodTitle' so they can keep adding rows/content to the html table. Almost like they are creating a recipe.

I just can't find a way to allow the user to keep adding the content to the html table like a list.

Here is my code...

```
<?php
// create a connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "DBPT_MP_breakfast");
// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
th, td {border:1px solid black;}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DBPT Food Database</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<section>
  <div class="form-fields">
<?php
      $breakfast = 'SELECT * FROM breakfast';
      $breakfastDisplay = mysqli_query($conn, $breakfast); 

      echo '<form action="" method="post">';
      echo '<select class="meal-planner-selector" name="searchFood">'; 
       echo '<option>Select a food:</option>';
          while($bDis=mysqli_fetch_array($breakfastDisplay)){            
            echo '<option value="' . $bDis['ID'] . '">' . $bDis['FoodTitle'] . '</option>';
          }
           echo '</select>'; // Closing of list box 
           echo '<input type="submit" value="Add Food">';
           echo '</form>';

//SEARCH FOOD DATABASE
if (!empty($_REQUEST['searchFood'])) {

$Search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['searchFood']);     
$sql = "SELECT * FROM breakfast WHERE ID LIKE '%".$Search."%'";
$r_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
$r = '';

        $r .= '<table id="foodTable">'; 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){
            $r .= '<tbody id="test">';
            //HEADINGS
            $r .= '<tr id="table-headings">';
            $r .= '<th>'. 'Food Title' . '</th>';
            $r .= '<th>'. 'Serving' . '</th>';
            $r .= '<th>'. 'Carbs' . '</th>';
            $r .= '<th>'. 'Protein' . '</th>';
            $r .= '<th>'. 'Fat' . '</th>';
            $r .= '</tr>';
            //DATA
            $r .= '<tr id="table-data">';
            $r .= '<td>' .$row['FoodTitle'] . '</td>';
            $r .= '<td><input type="text" value=" '.$row['Serving'] . '"</td>';
            $r .= '<td><input type="text" value=" '.$row['Protein'] . '"</td>';
            $r .= '<td><input type="text" value=" '.$row['Carbs'] . '"</td>';
            $r .= '<td><input type="text" value=" '.$row['Fat'] . '"</td>';
            $r .= '<td><input type="button" onclick="addRow()" id="add-row" value="Add Row"</td>';
            $r .= '</tr>';
        }
        $r .= '</tbody>';
        $r .= '</table>';
        echo $r; 
        }
?>
  <script>
    function addRow() {
      var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
      var col1 = document.createElement('td'); // create 1st column node
      var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create 2nd column node
      var col3 = document.createElement('td'); // create 3rd column node
      var col4 = document.createElement('td'); // create 4th column node
      var col5 = document.createElement('td'); // create 5th column node
      var col6 = document.createElement('td'); // create 6th column node
      row.appendChild(col1); // append 1st column to row
      row.appendChild(col2); // append 2nd column to row
      row.appendChild(col3); // append 3rd column to row
      row.appendChild(col4); // append 4th column to row
      row.appendChild(col5); // append 5th column to row
      row.appendChild(col6); // append 6th column to row
      col1.innerHTML = "<? echo $row['FoodTitle'] ?>"; // put data in 1st column
      col2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='<? echo $row['Serving']?>'/>"; // put data in 2nd column
      col3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='<? echo $row['Carbs']?>'/>"; // put data in 3rd column
      col4.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='<? echo $row['Protein']?>'/>"; // put data in 4th column
      col5.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='<? echo $row['Fat']?>'/>"; // put data in 5th column
      col6.innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='addRow()' id='add-row' value='Add Row'/>"; // put data in 6th column
      var table = document.getElementById("foodTable"); // find table to append to
      table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
    }
  </script> 
</div>
</section>
<?php  
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it will be easier with Jquery and Ajax

Comment: Hi, yer I started with this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) using ajax. I got that working, after a google search I also got the jQuery part to add a row but I couldn't figure out a way to add multiple content. it just kept replacing the original row.  - Does that make sense?

I must be missing something!

Comment: edit your question with the last thing you have made with jquery so i can help you

Comment: ok, I have added the jQuery part but I know I have done it wrong... I just can't find how to get it exactly how I need it! - my head hurts!

Comment: your problem is that every time you change the select box you refresh the entire page so the old record displayed on page are disappear so the best approach here is to use ajax to get data without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need two pages one for displaying the select form and the other is just return the data passed on post request to it and on the first page every time you the select box is changed make an ajax post request to the second page and get json array and display it using jquery

http://www.infotuts.com/fetch-record-from-database-using-jquery-and-php/

http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

http://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/

Comment: ok... thanks for your help... I have gone back to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) and I'll see if I can edit it to match what I need it to do... As this might be a little bit out of my wheel house do you have any links to tutorials that you can provide that might be able to help me knock this out?